# help with a sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two tables, a header and a detail table:

**header**
id
name

**detail**
headerID
dueDate
extensionDate

I'm trying to make a query that will pull the ID and Name of a header who's detail dueDate is 5 days from now (if extensionDate is null), or if there is an extensionDate, pull the header who has an extensionDate that is 5 days from now. Can this be done in a single query? I hope this makes sense.
I'm having trouble with determining if there is an extensionDate, and checking that, or if not, check the original dueDate. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select id, name
from header
where exists (
    select *
    from detail
    where headerid=header.id
    and (extensiondate = DATEDIFF(d, -5, getdate())
     or (duedate = DATEDIFF(d, -5, getdate()) and extensiondate is null)))
```

Notes:

1. `DATEDIFF(d, -5, getdate()` gives you a date exactly 5 days in the future, without the time portion.
2. If you had indexes on extensiondate and duedate, this can utilise them separately.  Compare this with the other queries presented here which will perform a table scan.

---

#### EDIT (also contains alternative query)

Why EXISTS?  First create these test tables.  About 8% of details will match the conditions, which represents 5% of header records (unique).

```
create table header (id int, name varchar(max))
insert header select distinct number, replicate(number, 10) from master..spt_values
create table detail (id int identity primary key, headerid int, duedate datetime, extensiondate datetime)
create index ix_duedate on detail(duedate)
create index ix_extensiondate on detail(extensiondate)
insert detail (headerid, duedate, extensiondate)
select number,
    DATEDIFF(d,-convert(bigint,convert(varbinary(max),NEWID()))%20 - 10, GETDATE()),
    case when -convert(bigint,convert(varbinary(max),NEWID()))%2 = 1 then null else
    DATEDIFF(d,-convert(bigint,convert(varbinary(max),NEWID()))%20 - 10, GETDATE()) end
from master..spt_values
```

Check the execution plans for the following two, using Ctrl-M

```
select id, name
from header
where exists (
    select *
    from detail
    where headerid=header.id
    and (extensiondate = DATEDIFF(d, -5, getdate())
     or (duedate = DATEDIFF(d, -5, getdate()) and extensiondate is null)))

select distinct h.id, h.name
from header h
join detail d on d.headerid = h.id
  and (d.extensiondate = DATEDIFF(d, -5, getdate())
     or (d.duedate = DATEDIFF(d, -5, getdate()) and d.extensiondate is null))
```

The first one is just slightly faster

Comment: @Richard aka cyberkiwi, good solution, looks similar to mine.  Wouldn't -5 be 5 days before today though?  You get my vote.

Comment: @bobs - it's a DATEDIFF not DATEADD

Comment: @Lamak you tested it? 95% of my (coded) posts are fully tested - this is one of them

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't you use join? Isn't there a performance gain to be had here?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT h.id, h.name, Coalesce(d.extensiondate, d.duedate) As NewDate
FROM header h
INNER JOIN detail d ON d.headerID = h.id
WHERE Coalesce(d.extensiondate, d.duedate) = DateAdd(dd, 5, GetDate())
```

Comment: Good solution. Except I only want one record returned per ID, also DATEDIFF() excludes time, which is what I need. Thanks for teaching me a Coalesce()! +1

Comment: @Nicklamort, I missed the one row per ID requirement. I should also have considered the DATEDIFF instead of DATEADD; I always forget that one. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful

```
SELECT header.id, header.name
FROM header
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM detail
    WHERE header.id = detail.headerID
        AND (
             (dueDate >= DATEADD(dd, 5, GETDATE() AND extensionDate IS NULL)
          OR (extensionDate >= DATEADD(dd, 5, GETDATE())
            )
```

The DATEADD function will keep the time component if dueDate and extensionDate are DATETIME data types.  If you don't care about time, you can alter the values in the DATEADD, such as:

```
extensionDate >= DATEADD(dd, 5, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101))
```

If you must match 5 days out, then alter the conditions to

```
CONVERT(varchar, dueDate, 101) = DATEADD(dd, 5, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)
     AND extensionDate IS NULL
```

and

```
DATEADD(dd, 5, CONVERT(varchar, extensionDate, 101)) = DATEADD(dd, 5, DATEADD(dd, 5, CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 101)))
```

Comment: There is no CAST( as DATE) in 2005

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name
from header 
join detail on header.id = detail.headerID
where extensionDate is null and
dueDate = DATEADD(dd, 5, CURDATE()) or
extensionDate = DATEADD(dd, 5, CURDATE())
```

Comment: this will never match anything

Comment: Richard - I haven't tested this so maybe. Can you explain why?

Comment: `getdate` returns date and time, so it would only match records that are exactly in that time 5 days later.

Comment: Conditions are wrong as well. You wanted `is null` not `is not null`

Comment: @Corey you sure curdate() is in MSSQL? It would be nice if this is MySQL, but then you'd use `date_add` not `dateadd`

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  h.id, h.name
from
  header h
  join detail d on d.headerid = h.id
where
  isnull(extensionDate, dueDate) >= dateadd(day, 5, getdate())
group by
  h.id, h.name
```

Comment: This will return multiple header rows if more than one detail row for the header row meets the criteria.  Might be okay for the OP.

Comment: It won't due to the `group by` which I added in my last edit.